# Using pinch zoom, drag and drop on same view

Tags: android, android-view, android-gesture

I want to use both pinch zoom and drag n drop on the same view in my app.

I am able to implement them individually but when I try to use both it doesn't work.

Here is the code for dragging

```
class MyClickListener implements OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());

        String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
        ClipData data = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes,
                item);
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

        view.startDrag(data, // data to be dragged
                shadowBuilder, // drag shadow
                view, // local data about the drag and drop operation
                0 // no needed flags
        );
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I use on a non custom view without pinch to zoom.

When I use a custom view which has a scalegesture listener and then set MyClickListener as its LongClickListener I only get the scaling function and no drag is started.

I tried to add the drag code directly into the custom view after detecting a long press on the view

```
public class TouchImageView extends View {
long time = 0;
private Drawable image;
private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, Drawable mImage) {
    super(context);

    image = mImage;
    setFocusable(true);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,
            new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Set the image bounderies
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    image.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        invalidate();
    } else {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            Log.i(EJ.TAG, time+"");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            long time1 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - time;

            if(time1 >= 1000){

                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) this.getTag());

                String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
                ClipData data = new ClipData(this.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes,
                        item);
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);

                this.startDrag(data, // data to be dragged
                        shadowBuilder, // drag shadow
                        this, // local data about the drag and drop operation
                        0 // no needed flags
                );

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }

            break;              
        }

    }

    return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // don't let the object get too small or too large.
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

 }
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out below given demo for pinch to zoom,translate and scale functionalities.Hope it helps.

[Example 1](https://github.com/judepereira/android-multitouch)

[Example 2](https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors)

You can ask if you have any further queries :).

Happy coding!

Comment: Example 1 cannot solve my problem it needs the image to fill parent in height and width. I will have several images and I will need to scale and move each one.

Comment: In example 2, I want to give the  fix size, i mean it must not zoom in, from the given size. So how can I implement it please tell me